# Dropbox value is nott adding meanwhile checkbox value is adding and showing in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need help. (.wc-pao-addon-select) is a dropbox and it has a price in (data-price). But it's not adding and showing in (.price). Meanwhile checkbox is working fine

```
<script>
    $=jQuery;

var fefaultprice = "<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>";
var currencysyb = "<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>";
$(".wc-pao-addon-checkbox").on("change",function(){
var selected = [fefaultprice];
$(".wc-pao-addon-checkbox:checked").each(function () {
selected.push($(this).attr("data-price"));
});
$(".wc-pao-addon-select:selected").each(function () {
selected.push($(this).attr("data-price"));
});
sum = 0;
$.each(selected,function(){sum+=parseFloat(this) || 0; });
$(".price").html('<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>'+sum.toFixed(2)+'<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'+currencysyb+'</span></bdi></span>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please show the HTML? An if you're really sure `"<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>"`  etc. give back the desired strings, use a String instead, not something we cannot test (a PHP echo)

Comment: Also, what is `selected`? Could you please [edit] to create a [mcve]? Also by `fefaultprice` you mean `defaultprice`?

Comment: You're pushing to a locally scoped `selected` Array - instead of making it available to all the functions (in the common outer scope)

Comment: Why is `sum = 0;` instead of `let sum = 0;`?

Comment: Why are you using `.push()` to Array on a checkbox `"change"` event? If you toggle constantly on and off that checkbox you're pushing values to the `selected` array ad absurdum.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need jQuery
- When using classes make always sure to reference to a target parent - that way it will not mater if you have one or hundreds of such elements on your page
- Echo your `price` and `currency` in a parent wrapper `data-*` attributes, not in JS.
- Most of the other issues are mentioned in the comments below your Question

Here's a remake of your Item amount calculator in pure JavaScript:

```js
const EL = (sel, parent) => (parent||document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, parent) => (parent||document).querySelectorAll(sel);

const calcItemInit = (EL_item) => {
  // Get elements
  const ELS_ckb = ELS(".wc-pao-addon-checkbox", EL_item);
  const ELS_sel = ELS(".wc-pao-addon-select", EL_item);
  const EL_amount = EL(".woocommerce-Price-amount", EL_item);
  const EL_currency = EL(".woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol", EL_item);
  
  // Get data
  const price = parseFloat(EL_item.dataset.price);
  const currency = EL_item.dataset.currency;
  
  // Calc
  const calc = () => {
    let amount = price || 0;
    
    // Add checkboxes values
    ELS_ckb.forEach(el => {
      if (el.checked) amount += parseFloat(el.value);
    });
    
    // Add select values
    ELS_sel.forEach(el => {
      amount += parseFloat(el.value || 0);
    });
    
    // Set Amount!
    EL_amount.textContent = amount.toFixed(2);
    EL_currency.textContent = currency;
  };
  
  // Events:
  ELS_ckb.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", calc));
  ELS_sel.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", calc));
  
  // Init:
  calc();
};

ELS(".calc").forEach(calcItemInit);
```

```html
<div class="calc" data-currency="€" data-price="12.00">
  <div>Item: <b>JS Book Of The Year</b></div>
  <div>Price: <b>12.00 €</b></div>
  <div>Extras:
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-checkbox" value="3.99"> + Book cover</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-checkbox" value="14.00"> + All pages</label>
    <label>
      <select class="wc-pao-addon-select">
        <option value="29.99" selected>One year old</option>
        <option value="10.25">Two years old</option>
        <option value="10.15">Ten years old</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    Final price: 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount"></span>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```